# Read data from external text file as separate row

Tags: formatting

I need to read this contents as separate row and use at different location.

How can I complete this in LaTeX?

```
% my text file contents are %
College Name
College Address
university Name
% end of contents
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always add a MWE (Minimal Working example), that shows, what you have done.  In this case, your question is very unclear.  Edit yourself the question, add a code block starting from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.   You can mark the code and type CTRL-K to format it as a code block.  From what I understand, you are trying to typeset a tabular?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile}
College Name
College Address
university Name
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readrecordarray{myfile.tex}\mydata
Second record is ``\mydata[2].''

\lipsum[1]

Third Record is ``\mydata[3].''
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did note a restriction that the file cannot begin with a `%`, however.